# ConvertTo-HTML and rename the headers and insert headers in Poweshell

Tags: powershell

```
#Created variable for hostname and date    
$hostname = hostname
$date = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyy HH:mm"

#Get diskinfo and convert to HTML 
$diskinfo = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object DeviceID, VolumeName, Size, FreeSpace | ConvertTo-Html
```

#Output file
$Report | Out-File C:\Users\user\Documents\test.html

Now what I would like to happen is to convert to HTML with a new headers which combines the above. How can I do this?

[Sample output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFsYa.png)

Comment: Use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) in your `Selext-Object`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if understand correctly, but you can do that in one shot by maniuplating properties as on below example:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select @{N="date";E={get-date}}, @{N="Drive";E={$_.DeviceID}}, VolumeName, @{N="SizeGB";E={"{0:f2}" -f (($_.Size/1GB)) }}
```

and then export to html..
in expression (E) you can perform more complex operations like:  "{0:f2}" -f (($_.Size/1GB
and on N you are providing new property name. At this point you should understand the concept